# What is the best way to split long line with several exceptions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Say I have next code:

```
try:
    ...
except (some_lib.LongNameError1, lib.LongNameError2, lib.LongNameError3, lib.LongNameError3) as e:
    print str(e)
```

As you can see line with exceptions is too long.

I need to split it to meet requirement about a maximum of line length of 79 characters and keep readability at the same time.

Actually I've tried to look through standard library code examples but haven't find any suited example.

Comment: What's stopping you just putting newlines somewhere in your list of exceptions?

Comment: Also look at the exception classes and see if there is a common (base) class that you should be catching instead.  Look at the [requests library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py) for a good example of a hierarchy of exceptions.  I usually catch `Timeout` instead of the individual ones or `HTTPError` instead of the specific ones.

Answer (score 5):

You could take advantage of using parenthesis like this:

```
try:
    ...
except (some_lib.LongNameError1,
        some_lib.LongNameError2,
        some_lib.LongNameError3,
        some_lib.LongNameError4,
        some_lib.LongNameErrorN) as e:
    ...
```

Comment: As a variant of this you could put the list of exceptions in a describing variable (e.g. file_related_errors) before the try/except. You would still need the above solution for breaking lines in that assignment but the except statement will be shorter.